# Design Crystal Report in run time by c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, runtime

Is there any way to edit an existing crystal report in runtime?

For example: I want to insert subjects in a table. Than I want to make the subjects name as the column in crystal report. Than I want to insert marks of those subjects in another table.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You can use the Crystal SDK to generate a Crystal Document object and  from their access both fields and data connection parameters. Be aware that changing fields directly on a report is **risky** as it means that updating the report could break your code. It might be better to present your changed data as the result of a stored procedure or view and then point the report at that.

The [SAP Srytal Sdk Samples](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-28305) give some excellent examples of modifying reports.